# Can I make a discord python bot recognize when a person in a voice channel talks?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently creating a Discord Python bot and I would like the bot to be able to recognize when people in a voice channel are speaking. The bot does not have to be able to recognize speech.

For example, if a member speaks, I want the bot to do an action, such as play audio.

Let me know if you could help or have done something similar. Also, if anyone knows anything about recognizing speech or monitoring the loudness of someone's audio, let me know!

Comment: Listening has been problematic to implement with discord.py and hasn't released in the official version yet , you can take a look at this [fork](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1094#issuecomment-715657628) if you really want to do it.

Comment: @Ceres can you post that as an answer

Comment: @goose.mp4, [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1094#issuecomment-689330625) is an implementation if that is what you are looking for

Comment: @Ceres No, I mean't post what you said in this comment section about your conclusion to spencer's question as an answer. I would but It's not really my answer. It was just a suggestion to allow spencer to flag this question as 'answered'. Thank you for linking the GitHub link though.

Comment: Its not my answer either, I would just be copying from the comment in the issue, and I'm not sure if it works either.

Answer (score 1):

Discord.py does not support voice yet, You can use [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) for now. I ran into the same problem and had to move to [@discordjs/opus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@discordjs/opus) or [opusscript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opusscript) both have voice support...

**EDIT**

You can either follow my path (*changing the whole language and library*) OR Use this:

what I found discord.py[VOICE] which uses PyNaCl (for voice support)

`python3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]`

To install the version that supports voice uses PyNaCl as extra package than discord.py for more details and more documentation about this [please check this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/1ee1b7feea81a70488b1fc2d89a700109c84f8fc/README.rst#optional-packages)

Comment: discord.py **does support** voice send, just not voice receive, it's currently being implemented [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/pull/6507) and will probably be released along with discord.py v2.0

Comment: I edited answer do you see the under EDIT part?

Comment: Again, discord.py doesn't support **voice receive** yet, your post didn't mention it, and suggesting someone to use an entirely different language is not a good answer in my opinion, which is why I downvoted

Comment: @Ceres Just edit the answer and add it yourself.